# RewriteRule causes Internal Error when filename matches directory name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, internal-server-error

I've made it so that `/user/username` successfully directs the user to `/userui.php?username=username`. However, if I change the name of **userui.php** to **user.php**, I get internal errors since the name of the fake directory matches the name of the real file.

What changes can be made so I can successfully name my file user.php and still serve to the /user/ directory?

**Working fine:**

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ userui.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Internal Server Error:**

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off `MultiViews` by placing this line:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

on top of your .htaccess. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. :(

Comment: You need to check your error.log and provide exact error message for 500 error here.

Comment: The issue is the error log doesn't contain anything. I only see three lines that appear when Apache starts. I've restarted the service and it still isn't logging the errors. The Internal Error occurs even with a blank PHP file so it isn't PHP.

Comment: Every 500 error is logged into Apache error log, you probably are looking at some other place. You will need to check `httpd.conf` file to see where the error.log is.

Comment: "nano /etc/apache-sp/httpd.conf" shows error log set to "/var/log/apache-sp/error.log". I just now changed LogLevel to debug. The error log now contains debug information but still nothing about the error - only stuff like "starting threads" or "initialized pool" etc. :/

Comment: Hmm but it is impossible for someone to suggest a fix without knowing the actual error.